# ROS2 Network Analysis

Tags: networking, ros2

I'm currently running a complex system with several dozen ROS2 (mostly C++) nodes operating simultaneously. I'd like to analyze the network performance of the system to identify and log the topics with the highest network footprint. What ROS2 tools are available that can perform this kind of analysis, and what steps should I take to use them effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You talk about network and topics, therefore I'll suggest one for each.

1. Network: you can analyse network traffic by using tcpdump [1](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Security/Examine-Traffic.html).
2. Nodes: You can use tracing to analyse the impact of each node and its callbacks [2](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/advanced/tracing/). If you have a subset of nodes you want to check you can always use command line tools to inspect frequency of topics etc.